# How to render special characters during HTML to pdf conversion using iText & XMLWorker?

Tags: java, itext, html-to-pdf

Hi i am using iText & XMLWorker for HTML to pdf Conversion (Java) as below

```
    public void convertHtmlToPdf(StringBuilder content, String path) throws Exception {
    String methodName = "convertHtmlToPdf";

    try {

          XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
            fontProvider.register("C:/Users/Aaryan/Downloads/arial.ttf");

        final OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        final Document document = new Document();
        final PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        document.open();


        final TagProcessorFactory tagProcessorFactory = Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
        tagProcessorFactory.removeProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG);
        tagProcessorFactory.addProcessor(new ImageTagProcessor(), HTML.Tag.IMG);

        final CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl();
        cssFiles.add(XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCSS());
        final StyleAttrCSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);
        final HtmlPipelineContext hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider));
        hpc.setAcceptUnknown(true).autoBookmark(true).setTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);
        final HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer));
        final Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);
        final XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        final XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, worker, charset);

        InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.toString().getBytes());

        xmlParser.parse(is2, charset);

        is2.close();
        document.close();
        file.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception in Class::" + className + "::Method::" + methodName + "::" + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();

        throw new Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

PDFGeneration works Fine. The HTML content  parsed for pdfConversion has special characters as appropiate entities as below

```
   StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
   content.append("<html><body style=\"font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Arial\">
    <p>Testes &rarr; &rarr; Vasa efferentia &rarr; Kidney &rarr; Seminal Vescile</p></body></html>");
```

The Generated pdf displays '?' instead appropiate special characters (arrow symbols) . "Testes ?? Vasa efferentia ? Kidney ? Seminal Vescile ". Where am i going wrong. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution has almost nothing to do with the code/classes/objects...

You need to set the CSS "font-family" with something matching your requested output char-set

for example, if you have your special characters inside the 'p' html tag, then you can set the below style with desired font-family:

```
<HEAD>
<style>
p {
  font-family: -good-font-family-
}
</style>
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

This site might help you [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp), but try to replace `&rarr;` with `&#x2192;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data i am passing through this conversion is long dynamic data fetched from database.Actually contents of a RTF editor(tinymce) are stored in database then retrieved and converted to pdf. Hence i cant replace each entity....